# Exponential of large skew symmetric matrices

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, exponential

I am looking for a fast exponentiation algorithm for large (~10000x10000) skew-symmetric matrix.

Skew symmetric matrices can be written as A=UQU^T where U is orthogonal and Q is block diagonal with 2x2 blocks. Moreover Q is the real Schur decomposition of A. Then, it is then easy to exponentiate Q by exponentiating each block.
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067307/the-exponential-of-a-skew-symmetric-matrix-in-any-dimension)

However, in Python, scipy.linalg.schur is not faster than scipy.linalg.expm so this strategy is not appropriate.

Is there any exponentiation or Schur decomposition algorithms that take advantage of the skew symmetry ?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If your question is about a specific library, please explain how/why the official documentation does not sufficiently answer your question.

Comment: @ddejohn I am not asking for a library recommendation, nor about a library in particular, but for an exponentiation algorithm that take advantage of the skew symmetry